# can't manage to break a FOR in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a "to do list" but when I try to use a `for`, for a "delete all," button I can't break the for and I can't add new tasks, thanks in advance.

The `for` that I'm talking about is at the bottom of the following code:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const addBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-add');
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
const empty = document.querySelector('.empty');
const btnEliminarTodo = document.querySelector('.btn-eliminar-todo');
const list = document.querySelector('.li-container')

addBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const text = input.value;

  if (text !== "") {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = text;

    li.appendChild(p);
    li.appendChild(addDeleteBtn());
    ul.appendChild(li);

    input.value = "";
    empty.style.display = "none";
  };

});

function addDeleteBtn() {
  const deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');

  deleteBtn.textContent = "X";
  deleteBtn.className = "btn-delete";

  deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const item = e.target.parentElement;
    ul.removeChild(item);
    const items = document.querySelectorAll('li');
    if (items.length === 0) {
      empty.style.display = "block";
    };
  })


};

btnEliminarTodo.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

  for (let i = 0; list.firstChild; i++) {
    if (list.length === 0) {
      break;
    };
    list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
  }

});
```

Comment: Why not list.innerHTML = ""? You probably meant `list.children.length === 0` also, but you don't need that since the "while" clause of the for loop should handle that with the .firstChild

Comment: Testing what `[] === 0` is will be educational.

Comment: There are a number of reasons this *looks* like it can't work; but without seeing enough of your HTML and JavaScript to reproduce the problem we're not really able to say exactly why it's not working. Please, read the "*[mcve]*," and "*[ask]*," guides.

Answer (score 0):

There will be many ways to accomplish the actual end goal.

You can simply empty the HTML with `list.innerHTML = "";`

or if you have to use a for loop, just use a forEach on the querySelectorAll of LI of the parent.

```js
const list1 = document.querySelector('.li-container1')
const list2 = document.querySelector('.li-container2')

list1.innerHTML = "";

const lis = list2.querySelectorAll("li");

lis.forEach((li) => {
   li.remove();
});
```

```html
<ul class="li-container1"><li>111</li><li>222</li></ul>
<ul class="li-container2"><li>111</li><li>222</li></ul>
<ul class="li-container3"><li>NO removing</li><li>222</li></ul>
```